# Subqueries for filters in joined sqlalchemy statements

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy, I have a one-to-many mapping between two tables: a table representing athletes and a table corresponding to athletes' scores.  Athletes can have an arbitrary number of scores.  I am trying to filter athletes based on the product of their scores.  Below is the code for the two tables:

```
ECHO = False
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=ECHO)
Base = declarative_base()
class Athlete(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'athletes'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

athlete0 = Athlete(id = 0)
athlete1 = Athlete(id = 1)
athlete2 = Athlete(id = 2)

session.add_all([
     athlete0,
     athlete1,
     athlete2])

session.commit()

class Score(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'scores'
    pos = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    score = Column(Integer)
    athlete_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('athletes.id'))
    athlete = relationship("Athlete", backref=backref('scores', order_by=pos))

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

athlete0.scores = [Score(score = 4), Score(score = 3), Score(score = 5)]
athlete1.scores = [Score(score = 2), Score(score = 1)]
athlete2.scores = [Score(score = 3), Score(score = 8), Score(score = 10), Score(score = 7)]
session.commit()
```

And here is the type of thing I'd like to do:

```
foo = session.query(Athlete).join(Score).\
      filter(PRODUCT_OF_SCORES_FOR_A_GIVEN_ATHLETE > 5)
```

Comment: So what you want is to get athletes that have like score1 * score2 * score3 > 5?

Comment: Yup, with the caveat that the number of scores is not the same for each athlete, so the algorithm needs to multiply whatever scores are present.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this fragment of code can help you.
Just adds hybrid_property at Athlete class.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select, func

class Athlete(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'athletes'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def product_of_score(self):
        return sum(r.score for r in self.scores)

    @product_of_score.expression
    def product_of_score(self):
        return select([func.sum(Score.score)]).\
            where(Score.athlete_id==self.id).\
            label('product_of_score')
```

and the query is:

```
>>> rc = session.query(Athlete).filter(Athlete.product_of_score > 5).all()
>>> for r in rc:
    print(r.id)

0
2
```

Comment: I thought OP wanted a product, and not a sum, of scores? Your code here calculates the sum.

Comment: The product can be found by taking the natural log of values, then summing them, then doing e^sum.  So the strategy definitely works.  What I'd like to do is use the original property in the comparison instead of a surrogate.  Meaning to be able to do `rc = session.query(Athlete).filter(Athlete.score > 5).all()` and for that to yield the same thing as `rc = session.query(Athlete).filter(Athlete.product_of_score > 5).all()`. More generally, is there a way to make one property a proxy for another in comparisons (greater than, less than, equal, etc.)?

Comment: @mikesol, that's another question, but it's possible create another property.
Please make a new question.

Comment: I just realized that exp and log are in mysql but not sqlite as native functions. So I'm back to the drawing board, as I'd like this to work out of the box for sqlite w/o user defined functions.  Is that possible?

Comment: @mikesol.  i guess sqlite have no a such native function. You may check it out from sqlite official site

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my own question.  I'm representing below in terms of the sqlalchemy core, as that is what I'm using these days.

The trick is to use a WITH RECURSIVE to calculate the product:

The Python code looks like:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, String, Integer, MetaData, \
    select, func, ForeignKey, text
import sys
from functools import reduce

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)

metadata = MetaData()

linked_list = Table('linked_list', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True),
    Column('at', Integer, nullable=False),
    Column('val', Integer, nullable=False),
    Column('next', Integer, ForeignKey('linked_list.at'))
)

refs = Table('refs', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True),
    Column('ref', Integer, ForeignKey('linked_list.at')),
)

placeholder = Table('placeholder', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True),
    Column('ref', Integer, ForeignKey('linked_list.at')),
    Column('val', Integer, nullable=False),
)

metadata.create_all(engine)
conn = engine.connect()

refs_al = refs.alias()

linked_list_m = select([
                    linked_list.c.at,
                    linked_list.c.val,
                    linked_list.c.next]).\
                    where(linked_list.c.at==refs_al.c.ref).\
                    cte(recursive=True)

llm_alias = linked_list_m.alias()
ll_alias = linked_list.alias()

linked_list_m = linked_list_m.union_all(
    select([
        llm_alias.c.at,
        ll_alias.c.val * llm_alias.c.val,
        ll_alias.c.next
    ]).
        where(ll_alias.c.at==llm_alias.c.next)
)


llm_alias_2 = linked_list_m.alias()

sub_statement = select([
            llm_alias_2.c.at,
            llm_alias_2.c.val]).\
        order_by(llm_alias_2.c.val.desc()).\
        limit(1)

def gen_statement(v) :
  return select([refs_al.c.ref, func.max(llm_alias_2.c.val)]).\
    select_from(
     refs_al.\
       join(llm_alias_2, onclause=refs_al.c.ref == llm_alias_2.c.at)).\
     group_by(refs_al.c.ref).where(llm_alias_2.c.val > v)

LISTS = [[2,4,4,11],[3,4,5,6]]

idx = 0
for LIST in LISTS :
  start = idx
  for x in range(len(LIST)) :
    ELT = LIST[x]
    conn.execute(linked_list.insert().\
      values(at=idx, val = ELT, next=idx+1 if x != len(LIST) - 1 else None))
    idx += 1
  conn.execute(refs.insert().values(ref=start))

def gen_insert(v) :
  return placeholder.insert().from_select(['ref', 'val'], gen_statement(v))

print "LISTS:"
for LIST in LISTS :
  print "  ", LIST

def PRODUCT(L) : return reduce(lambda x,y : x*y, L, 1)
print "PRODUCTS OF LISTS:"
for LIST in LISTS :
  print "  ", PRODUCT(LIST)

for x in (345,355,365) :
  statement_ = gen_insert(x)
  print "########"
  print "Lists that are greater than:", x
  conn.execute(statement_)
  allresults = conn.execute(select([placeholder.c.val])).fetchall()
  if len(allresults) == 0 :
    print "  /no results found/"
  else :
    for res in allresults :
      print res
  conn.execute(placeholder.delete())

print "########"
```

The result is:

```
LISTS:
   [2, 4, 4, 11]
   [3, 4, 5, 6]
PRODUCTS OF LISTS:
   352
   360
########
Lists that are greater than: 345
(352,)
(360,)
########
Lists that are greater than: 355
(360,)
########
Lists that are greater than: 365
  /no results found/
########
```

And the SQL generated to be inserted into the placeholder table made by the python function gen_statement (w/ indentation changed by me to be more readable) is:

```
WITH RECURSIVE anon_2(at, val, next) AS 
  (SELECT linked_list.at AS at, linked_list.val AS val, linked_list.next AS next 
     FROM linked_list, refs AS refs_1 
     WHERE linked_list.at = refs_1.ref
   UNION ALL
     SELECT anon_3.at AS at, linked_list_1.val * anon_3.val AS anon_4, linked_list_1.next AS next 
   FROM anon_2 AS anon_3, linked_list AS linked_list_1 
   WHERE linked_list_1.at = anon_3.next)
SELECT refs_1.ref, max(anon_1.val) AS max_1 
FROM refs AS refs_1 JOIN anon_2 AS anon_1 ON refs_1.ref = anon_1.at 
WHERE anon_1.val > :val_1 GROUP BY refs_1.ref
```

Curiously, the reason I'm writing to the `placeholder` table and then reading from it is because if I just iterate over the rows returned by the select statement, sqlalchemy 1.0 throws an error for the `> 365` request that yields 0 rows.  It should, in theory, just yield 0 rows.  However, when it the result of the statement is just inserted into the table `placeholder`, it inserts 0 rows as expected.